# Can you use non-AMD libraries with RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

I know you can use shims to run Backbone.js, for example.  But let's say you have a library that behaves worse.

For example, a library that simply declares functions in the global namespace.

Can a library like that be used with RequireJS?  If so, how?

Comment: To my knowledge you can't do it, but I'd like to know if there's a way too.

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "worse". Isn't Backbone also declaring function in the global namespace?

Answer (score 3):

You sure can. RequireJS has a ["shim" option in its configuration](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) for just that:

If it has any dependencies, you can list them here and *export* the global your legacy file usually produces.